# How to find the singular solution of this DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

How to find the singular solution of $8ap^3=27y$ where $p=\frac{dy}{dx}$?

**My effort**:

$8ap^3=27y$

Differentiating both sides we get

$8a(3p^2)\frac{dp}{dx}=27p
\implies 8ap^2\frac{dp}{dx}=9p\implies p(8ap\frac{dp}{dx}-9)=0\implies $ either $p=0$ or $8ap\frac{dp}{dx}=9$.

If $p=0$ then $y$ is constant.

Can someone please help me to find the singular solution of this differential equation?

Comment: @Moo; that would give the general solution, how will you get the singular solution from there

Comment: What's the definition of "singular solution"?

Comment: Is $a$ a real valued parameter? What are the domains of $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1):

A singular solution is a solution that cannot be obtained from the general integral (or can be obtained as a limit solution).

For equations in which the variables separate, as in
$$
y' = g(x)h(y)
$$
there is a constant singular solution $y(t) = y_0$ for each value $y_0$ such that $h(y_0)=0$.
In this case, given that the equation can be written
$$
y' = \sqrt[3]{\frac{27}{8a}y}
$$
there is a singular solution $y(t) = 0$.